# orders of magnitude of linear and quadratic approximations.

Tags: calculus

I am very confused with these.

1. What is the order of magnitude of the linear term? (Enter your answer as a power of 10.)
2. What is the order of magnitude of the quadratic term? (Enter your answer as a power of 10.)

The example.

1. The error in this approximation is $O(x^3)$. Find the order of magnitude of $x^3$ in our problem.
2. Compute the exact error term in the quadratic approximation.
3. Use the error to identify the order of magnitude of $k$ since the error is known to be $kx^3$.

I don't really get it and can't find any useful information across the internet.
Could anyone please help me and explain in details.

Comment: You've asked these questions without context. But for a start, if we have the expression $ax^2+bx+c$, then $ax^2$ is called the *quadratic term*, $bx$ is called the *linear term*, and $c$ is called the *constant term*. These descriptors tell us how a term grows as $x$ grows.

Comment: but how to express it as a power of 10? My topic was about the approximations, linear and quadratic and then the Big "O" Notation. Later on this question has appeared.

Comment: You can use the logarithm to convert a value to a power of $10$. As you probably know, if $y=10^x$, then $x=\log_{10}(y)$. So (for example) if we have $ax^2$, then the order of magnitude is roughly $\log_{10}(ax^2)$ (which you can rewrite all you like using the standard rules for logarithms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to evaluate the expression.  For example, if you have some function f(x), its quadratic approximation (using x=0 as our base) would be:

f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)*x + (f''(0)/2)*x^2

So if the question is, say, "what is the value of quadratic approximation for x=1000", then you would evaluate:

f(1000) = f(0) + f'(0)*1000 + (f''(0)/2)*1000^2

But if you're asking about the order of magnitude of the linear term, you want to determine the order of magnitude of:

f'(0)*1000

and express the result using scientific notation.

Likewise, the order of magnitude of the quadratic term would be the value of:

(f''(0)/2)*1000^2

also expressed using scientific notation.

Comment: thank you. but how to find the order of magnitude of $x^3$ if the error is $O(x^3)$?

Comment: my function is $15,000(1+ \frac{0,03}{12})^T-15,000$